# Dependable dropdowns in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create dependable dropdowns with Angular. After a lot of debugging hours I discovered that my problem is the angular version. So the recent versions of Angular are generating in my dropdown a new strange option looking like this `<option value="? string:October ?"></option>`.
So, after several fights I discovered that it’s working with Angular 1.2.27. 
I prefer to have it functional also with new versions of angular.

Is it there an alternative way to have it functional also in recent versions?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="supervisor">
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    angular.module('supervisor', [])
            .controller('testCtrl', ["$scope", function ($scope) {
                $scope.loanYears = {"2014": ["October", "September"], "2015": ["November", "December"]};
            }]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row clearfix" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<form id="target">
    <select ng-model="months" id="year" name="yearRequired"
            ng-options="year for (year, months) in loanYears">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>

    <select ng-model="month" ng-disabled="!months" id="month" name="monthRequired" 
            ng-options="month as month for month in months">
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So, to obtain the bad behavior see: http://plnkr.co/edit/aTwXhg5W8RHml9FpDX78?p=preview and then select 2014->September->2015->appears injected the strange blank option.

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody will put it in a html file. Please provide a JS fiddle.

Comment: Hi @BarthZalewski, thanks for observation. I added in Plnkr because in JS fiddle doesn't have the bad behavior, probably it ignored my Angular version set it in html.

Answer (score 1):

The empty option gets added by angular because no valid option has been selected. To get rid of this preselect a value.

example (add the following to your controller and try again)

```
$scope.months = $scope.loanYears["2014"]
$scope.month = $scope.loanYears["2014"][0]
```

Probably a better way to do this is by preselecting the month on ng-change

http://plnkr.co/edit/jeC7hEjnuvneoq0GR7xm?p=preview

controller:

```
$scope.setMonths = function(months) {
               if(months && months.length > 0) {
                  $scope.month = months[0]
               }
            }
```

in your html:

```
<select ng-model="months" id="year" name="yearRequired"
        ng-change="setMonths(months)"
        ng-options="year for (year, months) in loanYears">
```

Comment: Hi @rmuller. The first option is not working, I'll try also the second one. Thanks.

Comment: True, the first one only gets set once so only works on first load. The second one should work fine. Let me know

Comment: Hi @rmuller, still not working, but thanks for the try.

Comment: seems to work fine here (see http://plnkr.co/edit/jeC7hEjnuvneoq0GR7xm?p=preview)

Comment: Hi @rmuller, thanks for your comment. You have right it's working with `1.3.3`, but it's not with `1.3.4`. So, my porpouse is to create a solution that can work with all new versions or this is the "limit" of angular, being impossible to create a solution compatible with more versions?

Comment: Hi again, I don't know why but not it's working with a small exception, when you select an option in year field and then select in the same field the option "select", angular returns month `Cannot read property '0' of null`. Probably I need to put an exception somewhere. Thanks.